# Wacom tablet and adobe photoshop shortcuts not working

Tags: tablet, pen

My Wacom tablet does not cooperate when I want to change hardness/size of my brush in photoshop.

It works with mouse and shortcuts on keyboard, but when I use alt and click the button on my pen (which is set to be a "right-click") and then I press it onto the tablet surface and go up and down to change these values it just keeps showing eye-dropper tool as if the right-click was not decteded, just alt.(then I press button on my pen to check if the right-click is working at all, and it is. The problem seems to be when I press alt and then a button on my pen).

I checked my wacom settings and they are default:

tip - one click button closer to the tip - right-click second button - double-click

It worked in the past...do you know what else to check to see why is it not working at all or me now?

Comment: reinstalling drivers did not help

Comment: it worked in the beinning but for some reason it stopped. The shortcuts work well with a mouse right-click, but with pen it seems like the right-click works only for one click but cannot holds it which is necessary to make a size up or down move.

Comment: already tried this https://forums.adobe.com/thread/814630 - nothing worked

Comment: See this [answer](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-change-the-brush-size-in-Photoshop-by-using-the-two-buttons-on-my-Wacom-Pen) in Quora

Comment: Won't fix your issue... but shift/ [ & ] are the quickest way to change hardness